# Why is this matrix skew-symmetric?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, bilinear-form

Consider Bilinear Forms, and two real $n \times n$ matrices $B$ and $\tilde B$.

Suppose we have that

$$(Bx,x) = (\tilde B x, x)$$

for all $x\in \mathbb R^n$.

What can we can say about $B-\tilde B$?

(Note that there is no assumption of symmetry for either matrix.)

My thoughts:

From properties of the inner product $<.,.>$ we know that if

$$<x,y> = <z,y>$$

for all $y\in \mathbb R^n$, then $x=z$.

Can I use this same property and look at the bilinear form equation above and also claim that $Bx = \tilde Bx$?

Then

$$Bx - \tilde Bx = 0$$
$$\implies (B-\tilde B)x = 0$$
$$\implies (B-\tilde B)=0_{nxn} $$

This is apparently *not* true, and that from the bilinear form equation above, one concludes that $(B-\tilde B)$ is *skew-symmetric*.

Where have I gone wrong?  How can I show the skew-symmetry?

Any ideas are welcome.

Thanks,

Comment: As a counterexample, the matrices $\pmatrix{0&1\\-1&0}$, $\pmatrix{0&-1\\1&0}$ and $\pmatrix{0&0\\0&0}$ all have the property that $(Ax,x)=0$ for all $x$.

Comment: Hi @amd, how could I check this?  is the bilinear form $(Ax,x)$ *always* this mutliplication:  $(Ax,x) = x^t A x = <x, Ax> = <Ax, x>$?  I feel like we don't have an explicit formula.  I am obviously a bit confused, so I apologize for the simple questions.  I thinking I am incorrectly thinking of bilinear forms as inner products...

Comment: Inner (scalar) products are bilinear forms, but not all bilinear forms are scalar products. Scalar products are also symmetric (and some authors require them to be positive-definite). I suspect that there are sources that use the terms interchangably, which might be adding to your confusion. Any bilinear form can be expressed as $(Bx,y)$ for some matrix $B$, where $(\cdot,\cdot)$ is the usual Euclidean scalar product. However, $(Bx,y)\ne(x,By)$ in general. What does hold is $(Bx,y)=(x,B^Ty)$. A symmetric matrix will give you a symmetric bilinear form—a scalar product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot conclude directly to the skew symmetry of the matrix $A=B-\tilde B$ because you have the same variable vector $x$ in the bilinear form $$(Ax,x)=0.$$

In order to conclude, you can proceed as follows. For any two vectors $x,y$, you have $$\begin{aligned}0=(A(x+y),x+y)&=(Ax+Ay,x+y)\\
&=(Ax,x)+(Ax,y)+(Ay,x)+(Ay,y)\\
&=(Ax,y)+(Ay,x)\end{aligned}$$
Which proves that $A$ is skew symmetric providing that $(\cdot,\cdot)$ is nondegenerate.

Comment: Hi @mathcounterexamples.net, nice to hear from you.  It's weird, but can you point out where I had gone wrong in my question post?  I was simply following the properties of inner products and bilinear forms, both shown on the Wikipedia pages very early on.  I should be setting the vectors $Bx = \tilde Bx$, right?  (Since the above equation held for all x in the second argument.)  Then I get $(B-\tilde B)x = 0$, for every $x$.  Isn't this matrix $(B-\tilde B)$ then...the zero matrix?  I am a bit confused right now...

Comment: @User001 You get $Ax=0$ if you have $(Ax,y)$ for all $y$. Not if you have $(Ax,x)$ for all $x$. You have counterexamples above. Having the same variable on both side of the bilinear form makes all the difference.

Comment: Ah I see.  So, in your proof, how do you know to set the RHS equal to 0?  Thanks, @mathcounterexamples.net,

Comment: Because $(A(x+y),x+y)=0$ for all $x,y$.

Comment: Hi @mathcounterexamples.net, I am finally able to show what you are talking about now.  I have a silly question, though.  I am looking up various online sources, and the definition for skew-symmetry for a bilinear form is B(v,w) = -B(w,v).  But in our case, we have (Ax,y) = -(Ay,x).  There's no "B" on the outside of each bracket.  Is it just a notational difference?  And that the (x,y) is understood to be B(x,y)?  And is this bracket (x,y) is always the Euclidean inner product, right? So that (x,y) = B(x,y) = $x^t . y$?  Thanks,

Comment: $B(v,w)$ is a notation for a "generic bilinear form". It is a good exercise to prove that for $A$ a matrix (the representation of a linear map), $(Au,w)$ is a bilinear form. Indeed $(\cdot,\cdot)$ usually represents an inner product.

Comment: Ah I see.  I will prove from the definitions that $(Au,w)$ is a bilinear form.  Can I ask one final question, if you don't mind?  I've shown now $(Ax,y) = -(Ay,x)$.  But, again from the confusion of notation, I feel that we really should have shown this:  $(Ax,y) = - (y,Ax)$, which is defined as skew-symmetry in Wikipedia.  Seems like we didn't do that...for example, the matrix A didn't move over to the other side....what do you think, @mathcounterexamples.net?  Thanks,

Comment: So, what I have shown is that $((B-\tilde B)x,y) = - ((B-\tilde B)y,x)$, but I feel that we actually need to show that $((B-\tilde B)x,y) = - (y,(B-\tilde B)x)$.  What do you think @mathcounterexamples.net?  Thanks,

Comment: Unless...that matrix can be...moved over?  Like a constant?  Using linearity, taking it outside of the brackets, and then putting it back in, but into the second argument, and not the first?  @mathcounterexamples.net,

Comment: @User001 Please refer to the proper definition of a skew symmetric matrix: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew-symmetric_matrix#Properties

Comment: I think I got it now, @mathcounterexamples.net.  Thanks so much for your time.  Please feel free to comment further, if you'd like.  Have a great night :-)

Comment: You're welcome. I won't have a great night yet... it is noon in France!

Comment: OOhh ... it is 6am in New York City zzZZZzzzz.  The library is peaceful and quiet through the late nights here :-)  Talk soon!  Thanks again,